# ftp multiple files simultaneously and not sequentially in unix

Tags: multithreading, ftp, put

I am calling a unix script from a java program.
The script takes all the .txt file and ftp to another location
mput *.txt
But this sequentially takes one file at a time and transfer it.
Is there anyway to transfer multiple files at a time using any unix script

Answer (score 0):

FTP can [only have one command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191052/can-ftp-have-multiple-tcp-connection-for-multiple-parallel-file-transfer) (like `LIST` or `(M)PUT` or `RETR`) running at the time per client.

So you'll have to spawn multiple clients, each uploading their own files.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your server and client are, you might be better off using rsync, which (if you have a rsync server installed at your destination) transfers only differences, and uses one single TCP connection instead of a new one for every new file. But unless you have issues with connection setup (DNS queries taking a long time for every new connection, for example), parallel transfer won't help you, as your overall network speed won't increase.