# Rapid concatenation of many files

Tags: parallel-processing, tar, gnu-parallel

I need to concatenate 1 million files into one file. I just want to lower the number of my files as soon as possible (the compression level doesn't matter to me).
Is there a way to run tar in parallel? If not, is there an alternative for concatenating files that can be run in parallel?

Thanks,

Comment: Unless the files are compressed, reading/writing files is often IO-bound and doing that in parallel will not be faster. In fact, on a spinning disk, it should be slower (it might be a bit faster on SSD though).

Comment: @JérômeRichard Not always: https://oletange.wordpress.com/2015/07/04/parallel-disk-io-is-it-faster/ The real world is messy and not always predictable.

Comment: @OleTange Well "*RAID6 over 40 spindles*" is not very usual so it is not much "*the real world*" ;) . As for network file system it depends but parallel operation are really a bad idea on NFS in general (on all HPC machines I used so far, and in fact, admins advise people not to do that because it often impact the performance of the access for other users). It can be faster on parallel file system though this this quite unusual except on supercomputers. It would be good if the OP could specify the hardware but this is almost never the case in SO questions hence my general vague comment.

Comment: @JérômeRichard The blog post was written before I got my NVMe. My NVMe maxes out at 4 threads - which again affirms my conclusion: Measure - don't assume. Also you seem to equate network file systems with NFS. Networks file systems include many other file systems: sshfs, ftpfs, AFS, CEPH, HDFS just to name 5.

Comment: @OleTange Well for sshfs, all implementation I am aware of serialize the operations so I am not sure this is possible to do parallel operation (unless there is multiple streams with is a different problem). It looks like the [same problem appears for ftpfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191052). Ok, for HDFS (though it is extremely slow and tends not to scale with many small request, both in serial and parallel from my past experiences). But *theoretically*, I agree, nothing prevent a network-based FS to be faster in parallel.

Comment: @OleTange I fully agree for SSDs, but only for random accesses (contiguous accesses should saturate the disk) and current interfaces/implementations. That being said, I think the problem comes from the poor performance of current OS interfaces/implementations. I think deeper queues with a more efficient async interface should be able to saturate a disk. In fact, the recent work on IO-Uring in Linux tends to show that (at least for usual SSD because saturating multiple optane SSDs in sequential is a bit hard). So yes, the best is to test but I still think guesses help not to do tests blindly.